# iPhone Application gets slow while searching record from SQlite Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am facing issue while implementing search functionality in application. I have 2,00,000 records in my sqlite DB. When i start type in UISearchBar it takes 5-6 second for searching.

What is the best way to impment search function in such a large number of records?

Thanks in advance
Tejas

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: What sort of searches are you performing? Exact matches, "like" queries, or using full-text search?

Answer (score 0):

I think to manage these things NSThread is the best way.